# How to check if a certain word can be used for another word in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, division, readlines

Peace,

f.ex.:

ur word is `"AAAaaaaa"` and you want to check what words u can create with it compared from another list.

f.ex. in the list there is:

```
AA

AAH

AAHED

AAHING

AAHS

AAL

AALII

AALIIS

AALS
```

So the only output should be `"AA"` cause u can't create things where you miss letters.

I got this so far, but it outputs every word in the list where a `"A"` is included.

```
with open("sowpods.txt", "r") as check: #TOWORK WITH
        for line in check.readlines():
                for x in word:
                        for y in line:
                                if x in y:
                                        valid_words.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `filter`

```
    word = "ZZAAEE"
    existing = ["AA", "AAH", "ZEZE", "AAHING", "AAHS"]
    valid_words = []

    def cmp_str(exist): # exist is one item in existing list
        copy_word = str(word) # so to not modified the word
        for c in exist:
            idx = copy_word.find(c) # find the index of char in word
            if idx == -1:
                return False
            copy_word = copy_word[:idx] + copy_word[idx+1:] # drop the match character

        return True

    valid_words = list(filter(cmp_str, existing)) # cmp_str is called by the filter function
    print(valid_words)
```

PS: update the code as position of character should be ignored

Comment: Oh wow, thats impressive, thank you for the answer. Didn't know that function, however, in this case it works yes. But actually I've a little mental barrier, f.ex. if ZZAAEE is the word, it should output true if in the list is ZEZE, cause it shouldn't matter in which position the letters are. Could you help me figuring this one out correctly?

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks yes, nearly perfect for my purpose. But somehow if possible, I want if the word is "ZZAAI" it shouldn't outputt "ZIZZ", since letters cannot be repeadly used. So if "ZIZZ" is in existing, it shouldn't be in valid_words, since you cannot reuse letters. U only can use every letter once. Hope you could help me out with this method

Comment: sorry. i just found an error in my code. I have updated my answer. please try again

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, thanks for your help, I'll keep you updated

Comment: Thank you Sir, that worked. I just really don't understand how that works, since in def cmp_str u work with exist as parameter, but in the function itself when u filter cmp_str and existing, u dont really input anything for it. So I guess the existing list is somehow the "parameter" for "exist" then in this case?

Comment: I have added some comments in my code. Maybe you can add some print statement to help you understand the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can adapt a logic like this :

```
s= "AAAaaaaa"
list =["AA","AAH", "AAHED","AAHING", "AAHS"]
valid_words=[]

flag = True
for i in range(0,len(list)):
  for j in range (0,len(list[i])):
    if list[i][j] in s :
      continue
    else:
      flag = False
      break
  if flag :
    print (list[i] + " exists")
    valid_words.append(list[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: words = ['ZIZ', 'ZIZZ', 'ZZI']

In [2]: w = "ZZAAI"

In [3]: for word in words:
    ...:     match=False
    ...:     chars = list(word)
    ...:     for i in list(w):
    ...:         if i in chars:
    ...:             match = True
    ...:             chars.remove(i)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             match=False
    ...:     if len(chars) == 0:
    ...:         print(word)
    ...:     elif not set(chars).issubset(list(w)):
    ...:         print(word)
```

Comment: wow thanks Sir, this works nearly perfect for my purpose. However I've no really idea what is going on here. the only problem here is: f.ex. u got "ZZAAI" and he outputs also "ZIZZ" even when it shouldn't output it, because there are zust 2 Z's in my word, and "ZIZZ" cant be made from "ZZAAI". any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Check my edited post to see how it actually works. May be it helps in your second question too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Sir, I got it mostly. If I get it right, with this method with "issubset" it's not really possible to check, if the letters are only used once each. Or do we have to modify rset somehow, that the letter gets "deleted" somehow? How is the easiest way to get this done Sir?

Comment: So you want only the unique words or unique character from words?

Comment: I guess character. f.ex.: my word is "ZZAAI" and I compare it with the list full of words: it shouldn't output "ZIZZ" cause we don't ve 3 Z's, only 2Z's, but in this method it outputs "ZIZZ" cause it don't excludes letters which were already used. "ZIZ" would be okay, but "ZIZZ" shouldn't be output. That means, if a letter is used, it cannot be used again to form a word. hope I could explain that somehow to understand clearly.

Comment: I think I found an ideal solution for you. Check my edited post.

Comment: Notify me if you need any explanation.

Comment: Hello Sir, implented it, but ZIZZ still gets printed. :(

Comment: and I changed elif not set to elif set, because if its at elif not it prints every word in my long list